# handle key event in softkeyboard with edittext in android

Tags: android

I am try to handle event softkeyboard in android but when I press on enter key never generate any thing what I do ?? Please any one edit on my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnKeyListener  {
    EditText editText1;
    EditText editText2;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      editText1.setOnKeyListener(this);
      editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      editText2.setOnKeyListener(this);
      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

      imm.showSoftInput(editText1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }

     public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) 
      {
         editText2.setText("hello");      
      }
      return false; // pass on to other listeners.
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this code.
editText2.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

```
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {

                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

     editText2.setText("hello");                    
return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```